# Run A Batch Script Automatically Everyday

Tags: windows-xp

I have a batch file ( that ends with .bat), and I want to run it automatically everyday.

What is the tool I can use in order to automate my batch script running?

I'm on Windows.

Comment: I don't think this belongs to superuser.com -- server admin should definitely know how to run batch scripts automatically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use the Scheduled Tasks control panel applet (GUI interface) or the *schtasks* command (command line interface).

Instructions for the Scheduled Tasks applet are found in Microsoft Knowledge Base article [KB308569](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/308569).

Instructions for the *schtasks* command are available on [Microsoft TechNet](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490996.aspx).

Answer (score 1):

[Windows Scheduler](http://ss64.com/nt/schtasks.html)

Answer (score 0):

I have found windows scheduler flakey- jobs dont always start for various obscure reaons - permissions, desktop interactivity and the like.  It just didnt click with me as I have never had mastery of this tool.

I have had good luck with [cronW](http://cronw.sourceforge.net/) through the years and its interface is more like the cron that unix/linux users use to schedule recurring tasks. remember that the search path in cron or schedule is not existant and your jobs always will start in %systemroot% so you need to change dirs etc to get to where you need to execute the command.